# Chrome extension programmatic CSS injection error into active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to inject a CSS file into the active tab when a certain condition is met.
I managed to get it working only by adding `"<all_urls>"` permission to the manifest although in the docs it's written that `"activeTab"` should suffice: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab#what-activeTab-allows

With the code below I'm getting

> Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.

while it works fine by replacing `"activeTab"` with `"<all_urls>"`.
Why is that?

*manifest.json*

```
...
"permissions": [
    "activeTab"
],

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
]
```

*contentScript.js*

```
...
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({injectCSS: true});
```

*background.js*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.injectCSS) {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {
            file: 'syle.css'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The activeTab permission gives an extension temporary access to the
>   currently active tab when the user invokes the extension - for example
>   by clicking its browser action. Access to the tab lasts while the user
>   is on that page, and is revoked when the user navigates away or closes
>   the tab.
>
> This serves as an alternative for many uses of , but
>   displays no warning message during installation

You have to invoke the extension for it to gain access to the tab when using activeTab.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab